# regex wildcard find and replace notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, wildcard, replace

Hi I am trying to do a simple regex that is annoying me because it should be easy - I am using notepad++  and that might be filtering "differently"

here is what I have

I want to find inside the string `id=0&name=/1274-IMG_2919.JPG` the bit that is the wildcard `1274-IMG_2919` so that it becomes after it's replaced `id=0&name=/1274-IMG_2919.JPG -O 1274-IMG_2919.JPG`

here is what I have and it doesn't work

```
FIND:         \&name\=\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.JPG
REPLACE:      &name=/$1.JPG -O $1.JPG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your looking for a string with `-` and `_` but they are not part of the character set you define: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, this works for me;

```
\&name\=\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.JPG
```

(or briefer `&name=\/([\w\-]+)\.JPG`)

Comment: excellent!! of course!! - sorry bit too tired today lol needed an extra pair of eyes